# Which audio format and what compression should i choose for HTML embed?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have a web application that uses jQuery to load some sound effect on user request. The file is currently compressed as WAV 16bit and takes 415kb. I don't know what compression level or format should i choose in order to embed this file to HTML with small size and playable on all browsers.

**converting to mono didn't work**
I did try converting to mono which reduced size by 20 times and i was able to play it in Windows but browser fails to play it.

**pitch reduced size**
I slightly increased pitch for the sound which made it shorter hence reduces initial size from 415kb to 210kb.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) is a nice jQuery library that could be used to play the sound. You may need to customize the display of the player to make it hidden if you want to programatically play the sound.

You may need to encode the sound in multiple formats, but jPlayer can handle the fallback to flash if no native HTML5 audio support is detected.

**Edit:** mp4 and ogg can be played with most browsers. Modern browser support for sound formats can be [seen here](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/). Try ompressing to .mp4, .mp3 or .ogg - any of which could the file size by an order of magnitude or greater. Also, maybe a *mono* version of the file in one of those formates will play, again reducing the file size.

I think you really need to try different bit-rates depending on your sound quality and file size requirements. I would start with a 128kb stereo (if the original .wav is in stereo) .mp3 and reduce the bit-rate and/or channels if the file size is too large *for your requirements*; is this for a company Intranet, a public site, a mobile site…? A larger sound file may be acceptable on a company's internal web site but not on mobile, for example.

**Edit 2:** From http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

> If developers want to take full advantage of all browsers that support HTML5 audio, they'll need to create both MP3 and Ogg (and in Opera's case, WAV) versions of the audio file they want to stream!

**Edit 3:** A [comprehensive summary](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#audio-codecs) on browser audio support.

Comment: I know how to play sound even using javascript without jQuery and plugins. I want Sound Format and Compression Levels acceptable by all browsers.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more advice. If a browser supports a particular format, it **should** support the complete bit-rate range that format offers.

Comment: I will go with your approach because as you meant not all browsers can play wav format correctly thus i've embeded though jPlayer .wav, .mp3 and .ogg. jPlayer filesize is quite small so i can live with it even in worst scenario of .wav file being played

Comment: Whilst investigating HTML5 `<audio>` for another question, I found the [jPlayer documentation](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-media-encoding) mentions that to `.mp3` files with Flash, the sample rate must be a multiple of 11,0025Hz. Just thought I'd let you know :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the browsers to support it you will need some sort of Flash based player, which will be able to play an MP3 file.

If you are using a plugin such as jPlayer it embeds a flash player for backward compatibility (you can use MP3 files). jPlayer also supports OGG format for HTML5 native playback on newer browsers (as well as MP3)

Comment: I want faster solution than integrating player, if no other option will be available i will embed this play and compress using mp3 algorithm.

Comment: +1 for adding this plugin first, @andyb just gave me more reasons to use it instead of simple embed.